# Mongo Json Schema Validator AnyOf not working

Tags: mongodb, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have created the a collection with the below validation:

```
{
  $jsonSchema: {
    bsonType: 'object',
    additionalProperties: false,
    properties: {
      _id: {
        bsonType: 'objectId'
      },
      test: {
        bsonType: 'string'
      }
    },
    anyOf: [
      {
        bsonType: 'object',
        properties: {
          test1: {
            bsonType: 'string'
          }
        },
        additionalProperties: false
      },
      {
        bsonType: 'object',
        properties: {
          test2: {
            bsonType: 'string'
          }
        },
        additionalProperties: false
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The Validation Action was set to Error and Validation Level to Moderate.

When I try to insert a document containing the field **test** and **test1**, I am getting a validation error

```
Document:
db.dmt9.insert([{test:"123"},{test1:"456"}])

Error:

BulkWriteResult({
        "writeErrors" : [
                {
                        "index" : 0,
                        "code" : 121,
                        "errmsg" : "Document failed validation",
                        "op" : {
                                "_id" : ObjectId("5dd511de1f7b2047ed527044"),
                                "test" : "123"
                        }
                }
        ],
        "writeConcernErrors" : [ ],
        "nInserted" : 0,
        "nUpserted" : 0,
        "nMatched" : 0,
        "nModified" : 0,
        "nRemoved" : 0,
        "upserted" : [ ]
})
```

Since I am inserting a document containing one of the fields inside the AnyOf, shouldn't the document be inserted successfully?  If I try and change the Validation Action to  Warning, the document is inserted however I can insert any other field.

```
Test with validation Action - Warning

rs0:PRIMARY> db.dmt9.insert([{test:"123"},{test1:"456"},{test9:123}])
BulkWriteResult({
        "writeErrors" : [ ],
        "writeConcernErrors" : [ ],
        "nInserted" : 3,
        "nUpserted" : 0,
        "nMatched" : 0,
        "nModified" : 0,
        "nRemoved" : 0,
        "upserted" : [ ]
})
```

**Update 2:**
When I remove the field test I get this validator:

```
{
  $jsonSchema: {
    bsonType: 'object',
    additionalProperties: false,
    anyOf: [
      {
        bsonType: 'object',
        properties: {
          test1: {
            bsonType: 'string'
          }
        },
        additionalProperties: false
      },
      {
        bsonType: 'object',
        properties: {
          test2: {
            bsonType: 'string'
          }
        },
        additionalProperties: false
      }
    ],
    properties: {
      _id: {
        bsonType: 'objectId'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and when i try to insert test1 again I still get the error message Document failed validation

```
rs0:PRIMARY> db.dmt8.insert([{test1:"123"}])
BulkWriteResult({
        "writeErrors" : [
                {
                        "index" : 0,
                        "code" : 121,
                        "errmsg" : "Document failed validation",
                        "op" : {
                                "_id" : ObjectId("5dd51b4766ba25a01fbcf8e6"),
                                "test1" : "123"
                        }
                }
        ],
        "writeConcernErrors" : [ ],
        "nInserted" : 0,
        "nUpserted" : 0,
        "nMatched" : 0,
        "nModified" : 0,
        "nRemoved" : 0,
        "upserted" : [ ]
})
```

Comment: What do you believe `anyOf` should do?

Comment: I expect the anyof to allow me to insert a document with either field "test1" or "test2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{test:"123"}` fails validation because it doesn't conform to any of the schemas in `anyOf`, which need `test1` or `test2` as the only key.

`anyOf` applies each subschema to your instance, and asserts valid if at least one of the subschemas passes validation.

`{test1: "123" }` fails because the root schemas `additionalProperties: false` prevents any keys in your object not defined in the SAME schema object `properties` or `patternProperties`.

The solution is to have some duplication.

In [THIS](https://jsonschema.dev/s/N4IgziBcLAOgdgAkbEAXAngBwKasiiAPYBGAVjgMZqoA0CyqAhgCYsCWa7R8TANgAUATkVxCuOMPkQAzfmBz0khLCLESpURHGWMQAfXYtpwAL5LketJJpazFy6mtg0ARhPmGj9DYBMHr09lZngMAHkZaQBtL2QdS29MXGlUUgpqOljvVVEccXZJEyyEpxt3O1NixCCEvVYOLh5+YVz8wq05PgUsmst42qdsPC1U8ipbBxKQHPUCzQJ+2sJnNH8Kqt6p+s5uXkE1PI1pTu7daq8AXQRTEFoQdigYL1KXFJBXXwBmVGuQUyA) example (link is for in browser testing but draft-7 only), I've added root properties `test1` and `test2`. This will allow data where you have a key of `test1` or `test2` to pass, but given I don't know your requirements, I can't tell you how to modify the schema to allow an object with a key of `test` to pass (as each of the `anyOf` subschemas prevent it).

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "properties": {
    "_id": {},
    "test": {},
    "test1": {},
    "test2": {}
  },
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "test1": {}
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
    {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "test2": {}
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  ]
}
```

If your intent is to check that one of the things you are inserting has `test1` or `test2`, then I'm afraid JSON Schema cannot help you. JSON Schema in the context of Mongo can only check each item individually, and is not afforded the ability to validate a collection of potentially inserted records.

In the above example schema, I've removed type checking because that is not relevant to this question, and bsonType differs from JSON Schema type anyway.