# MongoDb Document Failed validation

Tags: mongodb, validation, schema, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I'm trying to use JSON schema validators in my test collection. It has **anyOf** validation rule which should accept **foo** OR **bar**, should my understanding be valid and correct.

```
Validation:

{
  $jsonSchema: {
    bsonType: 'object',
    additionalProperties: false,
    anyOf: [
      {
        bsonType: 'object',
        properties: {
          foo: {
            bsonType: 'string'
          }
        },
        additionalProperties: false
      },
      {
        bsonType: 'object',
        properties: {
          bar: {
            bsonType: 'string'
          }
        },
        additionalProperties: false
      }
    ],
    properties: {
      _id: {
        bsonType: 'objectId'
      }
    }
  }
}

Command to insert a document:
rs0:PRIMARY> db.myColl.insert([{foo:"123"}])

Error given:

BulkWriteResult({
    "writeErrors" : [
            {
                    "index" : 0,
                    "code" : 121,
                    "errmsg" : "Document failed validation",
                    "op" : {
                            "_id" : ObjectId("6ee51b4766ba25a01fbcf8u9"),
                            "foo" : "test123"
                    }
            }
    ],
    "writeConcernErrors" : [ ],
    "nInserted" : 0,
    "nUpserted" : 0,
    "nMatched" : 0,
    "nModified" : 0,
    "nRemoved" : 0,
    "upserted" : [ ]
})
```

As far as I know, MongoDB supports draft 4 of JSON Schema, as specified [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-fge-json-schema-validation-00#page-16).

Why is it still giving me an error code of 121 (Document failed validation)?

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: They are definitely similar @Relequestual! 

What I want to do is have a number of base properties along with _id and then allow only either foo or bar as fields in addition with the base fields, so to say. 

Is this possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Read my answer to the other question and see if that helps. The pattern in the solution is the same as it would be for you. After that, let me know if you think this question is still different =]

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @Relequestual, the post in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58951911/mongo-json-schema-validator-anyof-not-working), helped me to solve my question. Thank you!